# Where_in in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, query-builder

I'm using Codeigniter 3 to build a website. But now I have an issue with get data from database.

this is my Model:

```
public function Get($arr_condition = null)
{
     if(!is_null($arr_condition))
     {
        $this->db->where($arr_condition);
     }
     $query = $this->db->get('cus');
     if($query->num_rows()>0)
     {
        return $query->result_array();
     }
     return false;
}
```

In Controller, I use an array ($arr_condition) to get list conditional:

```
$arr_condition['Cus_team'] =  1;
$arr_condition['Cus_user != '] =  2;
$arr_condition['Cus_phone LIKE'] = 09900000;
$arr_condition['Cus_role >'] = 1;

$result = $this->M_cus_dal->Get($arr_condition);
```

My code working perfectly until I need a condition with Where_in, I tried:

```
$arr_condtion['Cus_id IN']= array('1,2,3');
```

But, It not work.

Please give me an ideal to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

You can do something like this :

In controller pass your where_in condition with another parameter like this

```
$where_in = array('1,2,3');
$result = $this->M_cus_dal->Get($arr_condition,$where_in);
```

*In model method get `$where_in` as second parameter as add it to `where_in` clause like this :*

```
public function Get($arr_condition = null,$where_in = NULL)
{
     if(!is_null($arr_condition))
     {
        $this->db->where($arr_condition);
     }
     if(! empty($where_in))
     {
       $this->db->where_in('Cus_id',$where_in);
     }
     $query = $this->db->get('cus');
     if($query->num_rows()>0)
     {
        return $query->result_array();
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you @pradeep,
I tried first way but the result in mysql is `Cus_id = 'IN (1,2,3)'`. So I will try the second way.

Comment: and what about the second way it is much better way to get desired result

Comment: should be like this `$arr_condtion['Cus_id  IN '] = '(1,2,3)';` check whether it is working or not but prefer the second way, pls let me know

Comment: Thank you @pradeep, I tried the second way and it work right. Now I dont have more time so I will optimaze my function base your ideal. Thank once more time!

Comment: I'm sorry, yesterday I used smartphone to check green for your answer. But I don't understand today the check until not checked. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you use where_in then your ids should be in array

like this:

```
$where_in[] = 1;
$where_in[] = 2;
$where_in[] = 3;
```

OR

```
$where_in = array('1','2','3');


$this->db->where_in('Cus_id', $where_in);
```