# Sql query 'IN ' operator is not work error?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I am using CI 'in'operator is not work sql error please check its and share valuable idea...

**table**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCSQw.png)

```
id   | coach_name
------------------
9    | GS
------------------
10   | SLR
```

**view and function**

```
$coachID = explode(',',$list['coach']);
$coachname = $this->rail_ceil_model->display_coach_name($coachID);
```

**show result**

> SLR

**need result**

> GS,SLR

**last query result here**

> SELECT `coach_name` FROM `mcc_coach` WHERE `id` IN('9', '10')

**CI code**

```
public function display_coach_name($coachID='')
            {
        $db2 = $this->load->database('rail',TRUE);
        $db2->select('coach_name');
        $db2->from('mcc_coach');
        $db2->where_in('id',$coachID);
        $query = $db2->get();
        echo $db2->last_query(); die;

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0):
            //return $query->row()->coach_name;
        else:
            return 0;
        endif;
            }
```

Comment: SELECT coach_name FROM mcc_coach WHERE id IN('9','10')

Comment: It must be `IN ('9','10')`

Comment: please edit my code and share me please sir

Comment: @Amitabhkumar Show how you are assign the value for `coachID`? That means the code before you calling `display_coach_name()` function

Comment: Your variable $coachID contains string ('9,10'). Just make it ('9','10')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50862421/10138734 - $coachID must be not a literal '9,10' but array('9','10').

Comment: edit my code and share me please sir

Comment: @Amitabhkumar As I said you are looking for solution you must have to add the code that how you are assinging comma seperated value for #coachId variable!

Comment: sir i have no idea please edit my ci code and share me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing this query

```
 SELECT coach_name FROM mcc_coach WHERE id IN('9,10')
```

it means you are applying in operator on a single id which contains a comma separated value. 
So, right query will be

```
SELECT coach_name FROM mcc_coach WHERE id IN('9','10')
```

Comment: but not working fine id best name only 9 id print not 9 and 10  sir?

Comment: can you share row of which id 9 and 10.

Comment: i am share top table image please check its

Answer (score 1):

You must provide an array to in operator so #coachId must be an array not a string