# Include more than one value to check in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function get_tertiarylevel_present() {
    $checker = array(
        'timestamp' => strtotime(date('Y-m-d')),
        'section_id' => 11,
        'status'    => 1
    );
    $tertiarylevel_present = $this->db->get_where('daily_attendances', $checker);
    return $tertiarylevel_present->num_rows();
}
```

Currently it is checking for 'status' value 1(Present only).How to modify that also checks if the database have 'status' value 3(Late). how to include in the array if there is more than one value to check.

Comment: Codeigniter 5? Isn't the latest version 4.2? And the syntax (snake case) looks more like version 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where\_in in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861360/where-in-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `where_in` ( https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::where_in ):

This should work (haven't tested it though):

```
public function get_tertiarylevel_present() {
    $this->db->where('timestamp', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));
    $this->db->where('section_id', 11);
    $this->db->where_in('status', array(1, 3));
    $tertiarylevel_present = $this->db->get('daily_attendances');
    return $tertiarylevel_present->num_rows();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

change where condition array to this :

```
<pre> <code>

$array = array(  'timestamp' => strtotime(date('Y-m-d')),
    'section_id' => 11, 
    'id >=' => 1
);
</code> </pre>
```

you should use 'id >' => 1 to tell orm what condition do you mean

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. As far as I see, your change does not check for two different values in the `status` column